# UITableView in html implementation

Tags: html, uitableview

I'm looking to build an html interface similar to how the UITableView works, including sections and cells. Is there any javascript library to help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it might be overkill, and you would have to style it yourself to get it to look like UITableView:

jQuery(library) with [jQuery DataTables: Alphabetical Search](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-alphabetical-search/) plugin has an index with alphabetically sorted sections and search, which seems to be the crux of the what you seek.